# How to use onKeyLongPress in background or something like service?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

How to use onKeyLongPress in background or something like service? I want to start my activity from another application(just long pressing on back key). So. I don't know where I should use this callback: in service or in activity.

#### Service

```
public class ViewService extends Service implements android.view.KeyEvent.Callback  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent( ViewService.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to use onKeyLongPress in background or something like sevice?

AFAIK, that is not possible, except perhaps from an accessibility service. Users will be unlikely to agree to allow your app to serve as an accessibility service, to monitor all inputs just so they can start up some activity by long-pressing the BACK button.

> I want to start my activity from another application(just long pressing on back key)

The only stock buttons that can be used as triggers are:

- the CAMERA button, for devices that have one
- the SEARCH button, for devices that have one (and that only for a long-press on the button)
- the MEDIA button, for devices that have one, typically via a remote control or a headset

The user usually wants the `CAMERA` button and the `MEDIA` button to control a camera and a media player, respectively.